# How to allow wordpress website browsing but no file write or create

Tags: php, file, permissions, ownership

I would like to know how I can setup a website in a way that I can browse the website normally but deny the creation or editing of any file except from the ftp access.

I have a wordpress website which gets hacked over and over. I know I have to find the exact vulnerability, but as a quick temporary fix, I would like to deny the website to create new php pages or modify existing ones but still allow update to be done by ftp.

For now all folder are 755 and files 644 and from what i can find, all files/folder are owned by the account user. I am on a dedicated hosting using whm/cpanel.

From what I've read, that could be doable using the file ownership, but I hardly know what group or user ownership to put on files and folders to achieve this.

Comment: There's no simple way to achieve what you're asking. Instead, you need to secure the site, not look for bandaid solutions. That's what the problem is with Wordpress websites. You should probably identify where the intrusion point is and resolve that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All malicious files are loaded directly from a file upload script. You can't deny wordpress uploading files. Wordpress doesn't know what is FTP. Via FTP permissions you change file's permissions (not whole website upload rules).

---

You have to secure your Wordpress. This process isn't hardly. Just do this steps:

- check if you have the last Wordpress version (update your Wordpress themes/plugins/Wordpress core).
- there are some plugins that hide that you are using Wordpress. Just search on google about "hide wordpress plugin" or something like this.
- temporarily you can change the rules of .htaccess file, to allow accessing admin panel only from your IP. Just copy/paste this code at the bottom of your .htaccess file:

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login.php(.*)$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxxIPxxx$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]

And replace xxxIPxxx with your IP address. The full article you can find here http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/limit-access-login-page/ .

---

I hope this answer help you.